# how to close or remove a specific image in a multi uploaded images functionality

Tags: javascript, html

Here I have multi uploading image functionality.

So here if the user selects Multiple images so using the below JavaScript code we can upload multiple images.

But here I want to enhance the functionality and the uploaded images should have a cross icon like close the image if the user doesn't want to upload the specific image he will be able to delete or remove the desired image, not all the image which image is not the good user can able to remove that image.

So please help me how can we achieve this

```js
var loadFile = function(event) {
  for (let i = 0; i < event.target.files.length; i++) {
    var image = document.createElement('img');
    image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[i]);
    image.id = "output";
    image.width = "200";
    document.querySelector(".cont").appendChild(image);
  }
};
```

```html
<input required name="images" type="file" multiple class="form-control-file" onchange="loadFile(event)">
<p class="cont"></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <input required name="images" type="file" multiple class="form-control-file" onchange="loadFile(event)">
        <div id="cont"></div>
    <body>
    <script>
        var loadFile = function(event) {
            var imgCont = document.getElementById("cont");
            for (let i = 0; i < event.target.files.length; i++) {
                var divElm = document.createElement('div');
                divElm.id = "rowdiv" + i;
                var spanElm = document.createElement('span');
                var image = document.createElement('img');
                image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[i]);
                image.id = "output" + i;
                image.width = "200";
                spanElm.appendChild(image);
                var deleteImg = document.createElement('p');
                deleteImg.innerHTML = "x";
                deleteImg.onclick = function() {this.parentNode.remove()};
                divElm.appendChild(spanElm);
                divElm.appendChild(deleteImg);
                imgCont.appendChild(divElm);
            }
        };

    </script>
</html>
```